# How to open modal jquery and get cell value from table?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, modal-dialog, each

I have a html table with data that draws dynamically with a JS function, and for each row I have a button that opens a modal bootstrap, how can I make that when the modal opens also capture the value of a column according to the Row selected when you press the button?

My modal html:

```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <!-- Modal content-->
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">

             </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                        info content
              </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
               </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And mi js funcion:

```
successList: function(data) {

   var strHtml = '';       
   for(var i = 0; i<data.array.length; i++) {

      strHtml += '<tr>';
      strHtml += '  <td>'+data.array[i].idUser+'</td>';
      strHtml += '  <td>'+data.array[i].age+'</td>';
      strHtml += '  <td>'+data.array[i].email+'</td>';
      strHtml += '  <td> <button type="button" id="btnOpenModal" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Process</button> </td>';
      strHtml += '</tr>'  
   }

  $("#tblUsers").append(strHtml);

}
```

i want capture idUser

Comment: Where is the html which contains the table having row with data? You can reference your row while popping up the modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener for click on button. And get data from event inside event listener. Use 'target' property of event object in order to get instance of button which was clicked.

Comment: Please show an example of code if you are adding this as an answer. A complete answer **must** come with a working example. As it stands now, your answer would have been **better if served as a comment** and could possibly be deleted by the *Low Quality Review* system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to make it more efficient.
You can create an object that will contain an array of key-value for each table row.
Also creat contractor.

```
 var demosData = {};
 function Demo(demoData) {
        this.id = demoData.id;
        this.status=demoData.status;
         //etc...
    }
```

When the table is created use the Constructor and pass all the data
On the link of open modal pass data-id.

```
            targets: 7, //number of column of link to modal
            data: function(row, type, val, meta) {
                var demo= new Demo(row);
                demosData[row.id] = demo;
                return (
                    '<a href="#" ' +                            
                        'type="button" data-id="' + row.id +'" data-toggle="modal" 
                          data-target="#Demo" onclick="openModal(this)"
                           aria-expanded="false">' +
                    '</a>'
                );
            },
```

When You clicking on the open modal you pass the attribute id to retrieve the object row from an array of the key values you created from the beginning.
After you get the correct object you render it values in HTML(Modal)

```
 function openModal(element) {
         var html = "";
        var demoId = element.getAttribute("data-id");

        var demoData = demosData[demoId];



        if (demoId ) {
            var id= controllerData.id;
            var status = controllerData.status;

            html = '<div class="row">' + id + </div> +
                   '<div class="row">' + status + </div>
                    //etc...

         }


   }
```